# Is there a startup shell script for Jenkins?

Tags: scripts

Hi I have installed Jenkins using

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Now there is a new user called `jenkins`, and Jenkins is started when the computer starts.  Is there a place I can put a shell script to start other services for this user as well?  I have tried adding `.bashrc` and `.profile` to the home directory of the jenkins user (`/var/lib/jenkins`) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are not designed to be launched trough .bashrc like files, but you have to configure them to be ran under the needed UID or username. It could be done in service configuration files, or sometimes in /etc/default/[service] config file, or /etc/init.d/[service] init script.

Comment: Thanks.  In this case it seems to be in `/etc/init/jenkins.conf`, although there is also a script at `/etc/init.d/jenkins`